# R Programming on Graphics

Tags: r

Suppose the following R code gives a multiple graph containing four graphs. There are enough spaces among the graphs. How to reduce the space between these graphs? Secondly, How to give axis name to only for the outer side i.e., from the first graph and second graph remove the x axis legend.

```
getOption("device")()

par(mfrow =c(2,2))

x<-seq(0.01,10,by=0.01)

plot(x,2*x)

plot(x,sin(x))

plot(x,cos(x))

plot(x,x^3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the margins argument in `par`(`mar`). The second plot x-axis is removed using the argument `xlab=""`:

```
par(mfrow =c(2,2), mar=c(4,4,1,1))

x<-seq(0.01,10,by=0.01)

plot(x,2*x, xlab="") # here the label for the x axis is removed

plot(x,sin(x))

plot(x,cos(x))

plot(x,x^3)
```